# What is difference between GetHashCode implemented in Object and ValueType class?

Tags: c#

I have summarized my question in following code snippet

```
struct Point
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public void PrintValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0},{1}",
            this.X, this.Y);
    }
}
```

above struct is derived from ValueType which contains GetHashCode method. Below is a class version which derives from Object and contains `GetHashCode` method.

```
class Point
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public void PrintValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0},{1}",
            this.X, this.Y);
    }
}
```

I just wanted to know. Is there any difference between these implementations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; value-types (`struct`s) by default make their hash-code as a composite of the values of their fields. You can observe this by trying:

```
var s = new Point(1,2); // struct
Console.WriteLine(s.GetHashCode());
s.X = 22; // <=============== struct fields should usually be readonly!
Console.WriteLine(s.GetHashCode()); // different
```

Note that `Equals` obeys similar rules.

By contrast, a reference-type (`class`) uses, by default, the *reference itself* for both `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`. The `s.X = 22` will **not** impact a `class`:

```
var s = new Point(1,2); // class
Console.WriteLine(s.GetHashCode());
s.X = 22;
Console.WriteLine(s.GetHashCode()); // same
```